# Stash: is it possible to merge one pull request into several branches?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Given we have a pull request we want to merge into several branches at once. Currently we have to create a separate pull request for each of the branches. Is it possible to create one pull request to be merged into several branches?

Comment: Definitely not.  There is only one target on Create Pull Request page as you can [see](http://i.imgur.com/3Z36CkF.png).  Maybe there is some plugin for that?  Just for the sake of my interest, why do you need separate PR for each branch?  For example, when we need to merge some fix to all current branches we make one PR to develop and after merging PR we merge develop to other branches.

Comment: We have a gitworkflow and its absolutely expected that we have to merge PR into several branches. We dont merge branches finally as they may relate to different releases.

Comment: It would be great to know more about what these target branches represent. We might be able to help with alternatives, or (as a product manager for Stash) I can consider changes we could make in future.

Comment: @MiamiBeach check out [automatic merging](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH036/Automatic+branch+merging).  Looks like what you talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version *Stash 3.11.x* This not possible. If you want you can create a plugin which would allow you to do this - there are none on the market currently.

More on plugins: https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/how-tos/creating-a-stash-plugin.html